# Отправка List из jsp в servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, list, jstl

День добрый. Столкнулся с таким моментом. Есть у меня два Servletа и 1 jspстраница. С одного servlet перекидываю List со своими данными. На jsp странице выдергиваю нужные мне данные при помощи jstl. Казалось бы все отлично сделаю servlet который будет их подгребать и все в огне. Но как оказалось. Выдернуть у меня их не получается. Пробовал вытягивать их при помощи request.getParametr и request.getAttribute.
По этому к вам уважаемые формучане появилось 2 вопроса.
1. Есть ли возможность перекинуть list из jsp в servlet?
2. Если нет, то как получить нужные мне данные?

Прикладываю код странички.

```
<tr>
        <td>ID карты</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="id_card" value="${card.id_card}" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Старые номера</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="old_card" value="<c:out value="${card.old_card}"/>" disabled></td>
    </tr>
```

При попытке выдернуть эти значения всегда возвращается NULL.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так и не нашел способа передавать весь list сразу на сервер. Но понял почему не могу получить значения этих полей. Дело в том что атрибут disabled запрещает передачу значений этих полей на сервер.

Comment: А нельзя создать json-объект с массивом, и его передавать на сервер?

Comment: Дело в том что я пока не знаком с json. По этому ответить на Ваш вопрос не могу. Но тут дело еще и в том что на странице находится 3 разных листа. Которые относятся к разными таблицам. По этому следуя логике скорее всего придется создавать 3 разных объекта JSON и потом на стороне сервера их разбирать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не нашел способа передавать весь list сразу на сервер. Но понял почему не могу получить значения этих полей. Дело в том что атрибут disabled запрещает передачу значений этих полей на сервер.